# How to say "I want to rub my face on your cat's fluffy fur" in Japanese

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning, usage

I have limited knowledge of Japanese but I tried to convey my thought by saying this to a Japanese friend.

> 君の猫のふかふか毛で顔をこすることが欲しい。

It seems incorrect. Could anyone point out what's wrong with the sentence or give me some suggestion?

Comment: 君の猫のふかふか毛で顔をこすることが欲しい。 translate it with google...

Comment: ^ GT translates it to "I want **you** to rub **your face** with the fluffy hair of your cat", which means 君の猫のふかふかの毛で顔を**こすってほしい**

Comment: “Are we not doing “phrasing” anymore?"  — Sterling Archer

Comment: @istrasci I expect to see OP's idiom as a *lewd* caption any day now.

Comment: Unlike English, the Japanese word 猫 has no sexual connotation. So 君の猫のふかふかの毛で顔をこすりたい just means what it literally means: "I want to rub my face to the fluffy hair of your pet cat."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the auxiliary ～たい for "I want to ~~". For example:

> - 擦{こす}りたい -- I want to rub
> - 食{た}べたい -- I want to eat
> - 言{い}いたい -- I want to say

So I think your sentence could *literally* translate to:

> 君{きみ}の猫{ねこ}のふかふか**の**毛{け}で顔{かお}を**こすりたい**。

(I personally would say something like... 「XXさんの猫ちゃんのふかふか(orふわふわ)の毛に顔をモフモフしたい～^^」「～～毛に顔をうずめてモフモフした～い^^」)